# How to query number of positional arguments to "".format()

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm looking for a way to determine how many positional arguments a string has when used with `format()`.

For example:

```
>>> "{0}, {1} {0}".format("Bond", "James")
Bond, James Bond
>>> number_of_positionals("{0}, {1} {0}")
2
>>> number_of_positionals("{0}, {key} {1} {2}")
3
```

I can implement `number_of_positionals` myself, but not being fully familiar with all the ins and outs of the `format()` mini-language, I'm worried about missing out on edge-cases.

Is there a built-in or otherwise solid implementation of this available in Python 2.6 or 2.7?

Comment: See [`string.Formatter.parse`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.Formatter.parse)

Comment: Thanks @PeterWood, I had a look but I can't figure out what it does or how it can be used to solve the problem.. could you provide an example?

Comment: See the second answer to the duplicate question.

Comment: Found it, thanks Peter!